# smart Assigning based on the vectors properties

Tags: c++, vector

Asana is exploring a smart-workload feature designed to streamline task assignment between coworkers. Newly created tasks will be automatically assigned to the team member with the lightest workload. For the ith person the following information is known:

```
namesi - their name, a string containing only uppercase and lowercase letters;
statusesi - their vacation indicator status, which is true if the person is on a vacation, or false otherwise;
projectsi - the number of projects they are currently involved in;
tasksi - the number of tasks assigned to the report.
```

If a person's vacation indicator value is set to true, this means they are on vacation and cannot be assigned new tasks. Conversely, a vacation indicator value of false means they are open to receive task assignments.

Asana sorts team members according to their availability. Person A has a higher availability than person B if they have fewer tasks to do than B, or if these numbers are equal but A has fewer assigned projects than B. Put another way, we can say that person A has a higher availability than person B if their (tasks, projects) pair is less than the same pair for B.

Your task is to find the name of the person with the highest availability. It is guaranteed that there is exactly one such person.

Example

```
For names = ["John", "Martin"], statuses = [false, false],
projects = [2, 1] and tasks = [16, 5],
the output should be
smartAssigning(names, statuses, projects, tasks) = "Martin".
```

The arguments represent information about two team members:

"John", with status = false, projects = 2 and tasks = 16;
"Martin", with status = false, projects = 1 and tasks = 5.
Here John and Martin's vacation indicators are both true, so both of them are open to new assignments. Martin is only assigned 5 tasks while John is assigned 6, so Martin has the highest availability.

```
For names = ["John", "Martin"], statuses = [false, true],
projects = [2, 1] and tasks = [6, 5],
the output should be
smartAssigning(names, statuses, projects, tasks) = "John".
```

The arguments stand for the following team members:

"John", with status = false, projects = 2 and tasks = 1;
"Martin", with status = true, projects = 1 and tasks = 5.
In this example Martin cannot be assigned any new tasks because his vacation indicator is true. Therefore, "John" has the highest availability.

```
For names = ["John", "Martin"], statuses = [false, false],
projects = [1, 2] and tasks = [6, 6],
the output should be
smartAssigning(names, statuses, projects, tasks) = "John".
```

For the following information is given:

"John", with status = false, projects = 1 and tasks = 6;
"Martin", with status = false, projects = 2 and tasks = 6.
Both John and Martin's vacation indicators are false, and the number of tasks each of them is assigned is 6. However, John is involved in just 1 project, while Martin is involved in 2, so John has the highest availability.

This is my code but it was not passed the exam test. What is my problem

```
std::string smartAssigning(std::vector<std::string> names, std::vector<bool> statuses, std::vector<int> projects, std::vector<int> tasks) {
    int indicator=0;
    int num_member=names.size();
    int count=0;
    for (int i=0;i<num_member;i++) {   
       if(statuses[i]==false){
           count++;
           indicator=i;
       }
        else {
            names.erase(names.begin() + i);
            projects.erase(projects.begin() + i);
            tasks.erase(tasks.begin() + i);
        }
     }

    if(count==1)
         return names[indicator] ;   
    num_member=names.size();
    indicator=0;
    int count_min=1;
    int min=tasks[0];
    for (int i=1;i<num_member;i++) {  
       if(tasks[i]==min)  count_min++;
       else if(tasks[i]<min){
           min=tasks[i];
           indicator=i;

       } 

       else {
            names.erase(names.begin() + i);
            projects.erase(projects.begin() + i);
            tasks.erase(tasks.begin() + i);
        }
     }

     if(count_min==1)
         return names[indicator];

    num_member=names.size();
    indicator=0;
    count_min=1;
    min=projects[0];
    for (int i=1;i<num_member;i++) {  
       if(projects[i]==min)  count_min++;
       else if(projects[i]<min){
           min=projects[i];
           indicator=i;

       }        

     }

    if (count_min==1) return names[indicator];    
    else return "";
}
```

Comment: What is wrong with the code when you run it? What is the behavior you are getting compared to the one it should be?

Comment: Actually. I do not know which is error. I passed sample test but fails with hidden test. Hence, I do not know input which I fails

Comment: Think about what `begin() + i` is as the vectors shrink and `i` increases...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're removing elements from the vectors, but iterating over their entire original size.
Also, if you remove the element at `begin() + i`, incrementing `i` will make you skip over the next candidate (which is now at `begin() + i` instead of the element you erased).

This will eventually lead to undefined behaviour.

Your filtering logic is also flawed.
For instance, the tasks list [3,2,2,1] would give a `count_min` of 2, not 1.

Since this is ultimately a sorting problem, I would solve it by sorting and not by filtering:

```
std::string smartAssigning(std::vector<std::string> names,
                           std::vector<bool> statuses,
                           std::vector<int> projects,
                           std::vector<int> tasks)
{
    struct Worker
    {
        Worker(std::string nm, int tasks, int projects) 
            : name(nm), workload(tasks, projects) 
            {}
        std::string name;
        std::pair<int, int> workload; // (tasks, projects)
        // As defined in the description.
        bool operator<(const Worker& other) const { return workload < other.workload; }
    };

    // Gather the people that are available.
    std::vector<Worker> staff;
    for (int i = 0; i < names.size(); ++i)
    {
        // Ignore people on vacation.
        if (!statuses[i])
        {
            staff.emplace_back(names[i], tasks[i], projects[i]);
        }
    }
    // Sort by availability
    std::sort(staff.begin(), staff.end());
    // And we're done.
    return staff[0].name;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. You are correct.